# String splitting in the D language

Tags: string, split, d

I am learning D and trying to split strings:

```
   import std.stdio;
   import std.string;

    auto file = File(path, "r"); 
    foreach (line; file.byLine) {
           string[] parts = split(line);
```

This fails to compile with:

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (split(line)) of type char[][] to string[]
```

This works:

```
    auto file = File(path, "r"); 
    foreach (line; file.byLine) {
           char[][] parts = split(line);
```

But why do I have to use a `char[][]`? As far as I understand the documentation, it says that `split` returns a `string[]`, which I would prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split(line.idup)`;

`split` is a template function, the return type depends on its argument. `file.byLine.front` returns a `char[]` which is also reused for performance reasons. So if you need the parts after the current loop iteration you have to do a `dup` or `idup`, whatever you need.

Comment: `idup` creates an immutable copy of the array. So if this is critical, you can always cast to immutable, if need be. e.g.: `foreach (line; file.byLine.map!"cast(string)a")` with `map` from std.algorithm. However, be careful with immutable casts in general.

Comment: You should not cast away immutable, unless you really know what you're doing. Doing so subverts the type system and may result in unexpected behavior. In this example, storing the strings across loop iterations will likely cause them to "change their value", since they will still point to the same temporary buffer that `byLine` used.

Comment: Yes, but in the general case a needed one. D uses slices to the original string normally, so without idup you won't do any allocations, idup allocates. However if you need the string accross loop iterations you have to dup/idup it, because byLine reuses the same buffer over and over again. If you don't need all the split up parts you might want to just dup the parts you need. e.g. split(line).front.idup if all you need is the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std.stdio.lines`. Depending on how you type the variable of your `foreach` loop, it will allocate a new buffer for every iteration or reuse the old. This way you can save the `.dup`/`.idup`.

However what type to choose depends on your use case (i.e. how long do you need the data).

```
foreach(string line; lines(file)) { // new string every iteration }

foreach(char[] line; lines(file)) { // reuse buffer }
```

Using `ubyte` instead of `char` will disable the `utf8` validation.